Tu auras mangé quand tu arrives ? vs. Tu auras mangé quand tu arriveras ?
Est-ce que la phrase Tu auras mangé quand tu arrives ? est grammaticalement correcte, au moins en registre familier ? Ce qui me dérange est l'utilisation du futur parfait avec le présent, mais la version Tu auras mangé quand tu arriveras ? me semble un peu trop complexe (probablement à cause de l'influence de l'anglais).
Y-a-t-il d'autres façons, plus idiomatiques, de communiquer la même idée ?

La phrase Tu auras mangé quand tu arrives ? ne respecte pas la concordance des temps mais surtout sonne plutôt mal à l'oreille. On doit cependant certainement l'entendre.
La phrase Tu auras mangé quand tu arriveras ? est grammaticale et idiomatique. Prononcée comme ça elle est soutenue mais des élisions peuvent la rendre de registre courant T'auras mangé quand t'arriveras ?
Voici d'autres façons idiomatiques de le dire :

T[u] auras mangé quand tu vas arriver ?
T[u] auras mangé quand tu seras arrivé ?

Dans une conversation relâchée, le contexte permettra souvent de rendre la subordonnée implicite et on pourra simplement dire :

T'auras d'ja mangé ?


Merci. T[u] auras mangé quand tu vas arriver ? - peux-je conclure que le futur proche est plus proche du futur que du présent ? Est-ce une règle générale? T[u] auras mangé quand tu seras arrivé ? - ça semble un peu ambigu, car seulement quand signifie l'ordre d'événements ?

J'ai dû corriger une énorme faute horrible ;-)

@Frank Merci ! Je me relis pourtant avant de poster.

@RogerV. 1. Oui, le futur proche se situe certainement dans le futur. On peut employer le présent pour un événement ayant lieu dans le futur (ex: Quand tu arrives, tu m'appelles) mais ça s'accorde mal avec un futur antérieur.  2.  Pas tellement ambigu, à moins qu'on considère que la personne en question puisse manger en se déplaçant et finit juste au moment d'arriver.
